# Flash FileReference Upload to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, flex3, upload

I am using a Flash/Flex uploading component in my ASP.NET MVC application. My action has a `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter. My action is called but my `HttpPostedFileBase` is passed in as `null`. Any ideas why it would come back `null`?

**Edit** -- I believe this is on the MVC side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do'h. My form fields weren't set.

Answer (score 1):

Get [the debugger version of the Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) you're using and see what errors the swf thorws. If you don't have access to the code of the component, I'm not sure there's any other way to figure out what happens.

Comment: Then probably the issue is on the .NET side and with that, my friend, i cannot help you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to integrate with FileReference to Asp.Net MVC Action 
you should set the action parameter name HttpPostedFileBase **Filedata** like this:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase Filedata)
{
   ...
   ViewData["success"] = "Upload Completed!"
   return View();
}
```

Hope it helps!